# Common menu Master Page for multiple project

Tags: c#, asp.net, master-pages

I'm currently doing a ASP.NET project in a team. The team member is all over the place, so we are creating different project for each different task we assigned to do. But we want a common top navigation menu in our project, we have created our master page for our common menu. We add the master page as a link to every of our project, but there is a error that not allow us to proceed on the ContentPlaceHolderID. It say "Cannot find 'Maincontent' in current master page or pages" Can any tell me what wrong in the code?.Im using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017 with .Net framework 4.5.2

***Error preview by browser from IIS server***

Parser Error Message: Cannot use a leading .. to exit above the top directory.

Source Error:

> Line 1:  <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#"
>   MasterPageFile="../Site1.Master" AutoEventWireup="true"
>   CodeBehind="UserRole.aspx.cs" Inherits="user_role.user_role" %> Line
>   2:   Line 3:
>
> Source File: /UserRole.aspx    Line: 1

**Master Page**

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site1.master.cs" 

Inherits="WebApplication17.Site1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title><asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="title" runat="server"></asp:ContentPlaceHolder></title>
    <link href="css/sidenav.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="css/topnav.css" rel="stylesheet" />
     <link href="css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="javascript/topnav.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="javascript/mainmenu.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href="css/accordian.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="javascript/accordian.js"></script>
    <script src="javascript/myTopnav.js"></script>

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body style="background:#e5e5e5;">
<form id="form1" runat="server"> 
    <%-- TOPNAV --%>
<div id="topmain" class="main" style="overflow-x: hidden;">

  <div id="myTopnav" class="topnav">
      <div>
          <style> 
              .menubtn{
                background-color:#1F4764;
                border: none;
                color: white;
                font-size: 13pt;
                cursor: pointer;
                float:left; 
                padding: 15px 10px 10px 20px ;
                align-content:center;
                height:100%;
              }

            /* mouse-over */
            .menubtn:hover {
                color:cadetblue;
            }
          </style>

      </div>
      <nav>
          <a class="menubtn" onclick="openNav()"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a>
          <a  class=' topbtn faa-parent animated-hover' href="Home.aspx"><i class='fa fa-book faa-wrench'></i><br />&nbsp;&nbsp;Home</a>
          <a  class=' topbtn faa-parent animated-hover' href="Configuration.aspx"><i class='fa fa-cogs faa-wrench'></i><br />&nbsp;&nbsp;Configuration</a>
          <a href="javascript:void(0);"  style="color:white; float:right; padding:15px 5px 5px 5px;" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()"><i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v"></i></a>
          <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" class=' topbtn faa-parent animated-hover' style="text-decoration:none; color:white;" ><i class='fa fa-sign-out faa-wrench'></i><br />Logout</asp:LinkButton>

      </nav>

    </div>

</div>
    <%-- SIDENAV --%>

  <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()" style="font-size:18pt; margin-top:5px;"><i class=" fa fa-ship faa-float animated"></i>&nbsp;CTMS &nbsp;<i class="fa fa-times-circle-o"></i></a>
   <div id="accordian">

      <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search">
      <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>


        <ul>
            <li class="accordian">
            <h3><a style="text-align:justify;" href="#" ><i class='fa fa-book faa-wrench'></i>Documentation</a></h3>
                <ul>
                    <li><a style="text-align:justify;" href="#">Container</a></li>
                    <li><a style="text-align:justify;" href="#">Supervisor Module</a></li>
                    <li><a style="text-align:justify;" href="#">Booking</a></li>
                    <li><a style="text-align:justify;" href="#">EDI</a></li>
                    <li><a style="text-align:justify;" href="#">Analytics</a></li>
                    <li><a style="text-align:justify;" href="#">Billing</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="accordian">
            <h3><a style="text-align:justify;" href="#" ><i class='fa fa-line-chart faa-wrench'></i>Planning</a></h3>
                <ul>
                    <li><a style="text-align:justify;" href="#"> Yard Planning</a></li>
                    <li><a style="text-align:justify;" href="#">Vessel Planning</a></li>
                    <li><a style="text-align:justify;" href="#">MT Storage Planning</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="accordian">
            <h3><a style="text-align:justify;" href="#" ><i class='fa fa-sliders faa-wrench'></i>Control</a></h3>
                <ul>
                    <li><a style="text-align:justify;" href="#">Yard Control</a></li>
                    <li><a style="text-align:justify;" href="#">Vessel Control</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="accordian">
            <h3><a style="text-align:justify;" href="#"><i class='fa fa-wrench faa-wrench' ></i>Operation</a></h3>
                <ul>
                    <li><a style="text-align:justify;" href="#">Gate Operation</a></li>
                    <li><a style="text-align:justify;" href="#">Yard Operation</a></li>
                    <li><a style="text-align:justify;" href="#">Vessel Operation</a></li>
                    <li><a style="text-align:justify;" href="#">Queue Management</a></li>
                    <li><a style="text-align:justify;" href="#">Reefer Services</a></li>
                    <li><a style="text-align:justify;" href="#">CFS</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="accordian">
            <h3><a style="text-align:justify;" href="#" ><i class='fa fa-dashboard faa-wrench'></i>Insights</a></h3>
                <ul>
                    <li><a style="text-align:justify;" href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
                    <li><a style="text-align:justify;" href="#">Enquiry</a></li>
                    <li><a style="text-align:justify;" href="#">Reports</a></li>
                    <li><a style="text-align:justify;" href="#">Statistics</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="accordian">
            <h3><a style="text-align:justify;" href="#" ><i class='fa fa-briefcase faa-wrench'></i>Resources</a></h3>
                <ul>
                    <li><a style="text-align:justify;" href="#"> Equipment Management</a></li>
                    <li><a style="text-align:justify;" href="#">Incentive</a></li>
                    <li><a style="text-align:justify;" href="#">Setup</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
             <li class="accordian">
            <h3><a style="text-align:justify;" href="#" ><i class='fa fa-cogs faa-wrench'></i>Configuration</a></h3>
                <ul>
                    <li><a style="text-align:justify;" href="#">System Maintenance</a></li>
                    <li><a style="text-align:justify;"href="#">System Administration</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>       
        </ul>
</div>
</div>

    <script>
        function openNav() {
            document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
            document.getElementById("topmain").style.marginLeft = "250px";

            document.getElementById("bodyframe").style.marginLeft = "285px";

        }

        function closeNav() {
            document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
            document.getElementById("topmain").style.marginLeft = "0";
            document.getElementById("bodyframe").style.marginLeft = "0";
        }

    </script>

          <div id="bodyframe" class="bodyframe" style="overflow-x: hidden;">


            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Maincontent" runat="server" >
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>

        </div>
    </form>    
</body>
</html>
```

**Web Page Home.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="../Site1.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="UserRole.aspx.cs" Inherits="user_role.user_role" %>


<asp:Content runat="server" ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="Maincontent">

    <%--<div class="jumbotron">--%>

    <div class="form-horizontal">

        <h4><span style= "vertical-align:middle; width:80%; display: inline-block;"><%: Title %></span>
</h4>            

</asp:Content>
```

Comment: How the master page folder structure looks like? The error sounds self-explanatory: it tries to get current root path but the content page is "*already on the root directory*".

Comment: "The team member is all over the place, so we are creating different project for each different task we assigned to do."...surely that's a use case for shared source control (e.g. using something online like VSTS or GitHub or whatever) rather than creating totally separate projects?? Anyway AFAIK you can't reference a master (or any other) page which is outside the current project folder, as Tetsuya has already alluded to.

Comment: hmmm source control?. im not use to that, but that sound like a solution to me. I will try to look into that. thank you very much